# UILabel, UITableViewCell from ViewController is invalid .. Outlets cannot connected to repeating content

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, viewcontroller

I want to make a `UITableView` in `ViewController`. But when I try to initialise `UITableViewCell` or `UILabel`, it gives error. After that I tried making a custom class (class) for that storyboard with `TableViewController` , it gave the error:

> "thread 1 signal SIGABRT "

Maybe it gave error because I changed other class. I really don't know how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: are you using .xib ?

Comment: just capital one field of your status_id or one is STATUS_ID your problem solve

Comment: i using xcode 8 ..

Comment: I updated my image.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect outlets from View Controller Class to the elements of a `UITableViewCell`.

`UITableViewCell` repeats itself, hence outlet of `status_id` will be created inside your *Custom UITableViewCell class*.

You have to create an `UITableViewCell` Class for the Cell.

Comment: Ok .. I create new UITableViewCell ... then how to link data from ViewController to status_id in UITableViewCell ?

Comment: Buddy, you really need to check for online tutorial on _"How to work with Tableview and custom cell?"_.

Comment: Ok Thank so much.. If you have link tutorial (worked) , i hope you can share with me .. Thank again

Answer (score 0):

Outlets cannot connected to repeating content---this error occurs when you try to connect an outlet in uitableviewcell to the main class..you need to subclass uitableviewcell and connect outlet  to  that class